# MySQL cast as decimal not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal

This query:

`SELECT CAST(30.123456789012345 AS DECIMAL(16,16))`

Returns `0.9999999999999999`.

Unless I got it completely wrong, it should return `30.1234567890123450`.

Can anyone please explain what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need `DECIMAL(18,16)`.

`16,16` reserves all 16 available digits of precision for values to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! I didn't quite get the reason `16,16` didn't work properly - is that the case when I'm using the same values as arguments?

Comment: @Ivanhoe123 - Yes if you use `decimal(n,n)` you are reserving no places for anything to the left of the decimal. You need 2 places to fit `30` and `18-16=2`

Answer (score 2):

`DECIMAL(18, 16)` should work. As you can read on [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html):

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The
>   ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.1 are as follows:
>
> M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1
>   to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the
>   scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

So `DECIMAL(16,16)` tells MySQL to use all digits as decimal digits, without any integer part.